# get users before and after a specific user with its rank

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id|name|points
1|Ralph|15
2|Dave|2
3|Mourphy|180
```

I need to get the user with id x and 5 users before and after him based on points rank:

I can retrive the user with

```
select *,rank() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC ) as rank from client where id = x;
```

How to retrive the others ?

Thank you

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: why do you need sample data? @fa06? Seems like the answer is pretty straight forward.

Comment: may be straight forward may be not - based on assumption how you can u answer accurately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already gave the answer inside your question.
It would be (Sql Server style)

```
DECLARE @myRank int
SELECT @myRank = rank() OVER (Order BY points DESC) FROM client WHERE id = x;

Select *, rank() OVER (Order BY points DESC) as rank
FROM client 
HAVING rank between (@myRank - 5) and (@myRank +5);
```

If you want it in pure SQL, you'll have to work a little extra, but it's the same idea (just with sub-queries).

Answer (score 1):

One method is to calculate the rank for "x" and to compare that to the rank for each row:

```
select c.*
from (select max(case when id = @x then rank end) over () as x_rank
      from (select c.*, rank() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC ) as rank 
            from client c
           ) c
     ) c
where rank >= x_rank - 5 and rank <= x_rank + 5;
```

Note that this may not return exactly 11 rows if you have ties.

If you want exactly 5 before and after *plus* all rows with the same score:

```
with c as (
      select max(case when id = @x then rank end) over () as x_rank
      from (select c.*, rank() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC ) as rank 
            from client c
           ) c
     )
(select c.*
 from c
 where rank < x_rank
 order by rank desc
 limit 5
) union all
(select c.*
 from c
 where rank = x_rank
) union all
(select c.*
 from c
 where rank > x_rank
 order by rank asc
 limit 5
) ;
```

Comment: thanks, can we perform this using rank() function ?

Comment: @Zatla00 . . . All of these answers uses the `rank()` function.

Comment: @LongChalk . . . The first query is not particularly long.  The issue is that it does not handle ties.

Comment: @LongChalk . . . I think you miss the point.  The original answer to this question was posted a noticeable amount of time before your answer.  In addition, this answer explains the issues with that answer and provides a work-around.